# How to get push notifications for a user tweets on Twitter for iPhone on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, twitter

I can change the twitter setting on iOS 6, but in the latest version of Twitter on iOS 7, there is no "Turn on notification" button in the user's setting.

How can I set this?

This is how to on iOS 6
http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Push-Notifications-for-a-Users-Tweets-on-Twitter-for-iPhone

Comment: This is on the Twitter site itself

Answer (score 1):

The settings you're looking for were moved by Twitter to **their site**.

Next to that, if you open the **Twitter.app** on **iOS 7** you can:

1. Click on the settings-wheel when viewing your own page.
2. Click on "settings"
3. Click your account name
4. Here you can manage the settings to get push notifications about each item (or not)

Answer (score -1):

You can now turn on notifications for users you follow on iOS 10 by clicking on the bell icon near the top right of their profile.

Comment: In order to help others that might see your answer a year, or more, from now, it's always best to indicate what version of iOS you're answer refers to.  The OP was asking about iOS 6 & 7.

Comment: @fsb good point. Keep in mind you can edit a post yourself and add "10" instead of asking me to do so. Is that really enough of a reason to give me down votes?

Comment: I'm aware I can edit your answer, thanks.  If I do that then it prevents you from learning how you can improve your answers in the future; I'm trying to help you get more upvotes.  Also,  I didn't downvote your answer, I'm not the only person on the site right now.

Comment: @fsb Makes sense, thanks. I guess I assumed I would be notified of an edit.